# Building Hbase on eclipse using Maven (The import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tmpl cannot be resolved)

Tags: eclipse, maven, hbase

I use the maven to import Hbase source on eclipse.
But there has a error that is "The import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tmpl cannot be resolved)".
I had find the tmpl package , but its "jamon".
How to find the tmpl package, and its "java"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can find the tmpl package on Hbase.bin.tar, and import the extend tmpl.jar
It will work.